# Geometry A, B, C are three collinear points

Tags: geometry

Okay, this is for my exam preparation.

The question is: $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three collinear points such that $AB=12$, $BC=2$ and $AC=10$.

Is the point $B$ between points $A$ and $C$?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about points in $\mathbb{R^2}$:

If they were colinear then $AC=AB+BC$ for $B$ between $A,C$.

Comment: A little more simple, this is just basic geometry

Comment: Draw a line in the plane and mark three points A,B,C with B between A,C. The distance AC is equal to the sum of the distances AB and BC since A,B,C are colinear. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have collinear points, so draw a line. Let's start with the two points farthest from each other--in particular, put points $A$ and $B$ on the line, and mark the distance between them as $12.$

Now, we need to put $C$ on the line so that $C$ is $2$ away from $B$ and $10$ away from $A.$ Once we've done that, the answer to the question should be clear.

---

For a proof that isn't "by pictures," note that since the three points lie on a line, then the distance between the two that are furthest apart should be the sum of the other two distances. Which point lies in the middle of the other two, then?